# sharing gif with telegram android

Tags: android

I want to share an animated gif file with telegram. I'm using following code:

```
 Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/gif");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + FOLDER_NAME
                        + fileName + ".gif"));
                share.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");

                startActivity(share);
```

this code open telegram but when I select a chat; there is not any thing to share.

Excuse me for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing code to

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/gif");

                String imagePath = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + FOLDER_NAME
                        + fileName + ".gif";    
                File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);

                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                share.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");

                startActivity(share);
```